# Выбрать из общей таблицы по 3 записи каждого типа

Tags: sql, postgresql

Таблица **project**:

```
id |    name    | customer_id
 1 | Project 1  |      1
 2 | Project 2  |      1
 3 | Project 3  |      2
 4 | Project 4  |      2
 5 | Project 5  |      2
 6 | Project 6  |      3
 7 | Project 7  |      3
 8 | Project 8  |      3
 9 | Project 9  |      3
10 | Project 10 |      3
```

Таблица **customer**:

```
id | name
 1 | Customer 1
 2 | Customer 2
 3 | Customer 3
```

Результат должен быть таким:

```
customer.name | project.name
  Customer 2  |  Project 3
  Customer 2  |  Project 4
  Customer 2  |  Project 5
  Customer 3  |  Project 6
  Customer 3  |  Project 7
  Customer 3  |  Project 8
```

Пробовал следующий запрос, но он не работает (*подзапрос в выражении вернул больше одной строки*):

```
SELECT
    c.name,
    (
        SELECT p.name
        FROM project p
        WHERE p.customer_id = c.id
        LIMIT 3
    )
FROM
    customer c;
```

Answer (score 1):

В етом случае можно исспользовать cross join lateral.

```sql
SELECT c.name, l.*
FROM customer c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
 (SELECT p.name pname FROM project p WHERE p.customer_id = c.id LIMIT 3) l;
```

Удаление тех, у кого <3 результатов:

```sql
with t as
(
 SELECT c.name, l.*, count(*) over (partition by c.id) pcnt
 FROM customer c 
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT p.name pname FROM project p WHERE p.customer_id = c.id LIMIT 3) l
) 
select name, pname from t where pcnt = 3 order by pname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий запрос исрользующий `window functions` :

```
with data as (
  select 
    c.name customer_name, 
    p.name project, 
    row_number() over (partition by p.customer_id) rn, 
    count(*) over (partition by p.customer_id) cnt 
  from 
    project p 
    join customer c on p.customer_id = c.id
) 
select  customer_name, project 
from data 
where cnt > 2 and rn < 4;
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d0b00ac52d83af5df74e3f860a41ff7f&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)